# Missing Simulator Devices in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode-simulator

When programming with Xcode (8.3.3), the "View as" feature displays the   user interface on many simulated Apple devices. Yesterday, I could choose among the following devices.

- AppleTV
- iPad (5th generation)
- iPad Air
- iPad Air 2
- iPad Pro (9.7 inch)
- iPad Pro (10.5 inch)
- iPad Pro (12.9 inch)
- iPad Pro (12.9 inch) (2nd generation)
- iPhone 5
- iPhone 5s
- iPhone 6
- iPhone 6 Plus
- iPhone 7
- iPhone 7 Plus
- iPhone SE

Today, these devices are still listed in the Scheme Editor next to the "Play and "Stop" buttons (build and run, stop icons), as shown below.

[image: Xcode Available Devices]

However, today, I have only a subset of the devices to use with the "View as" feature, as listed and illustrated below.

- iPad Pro (12.9 inch)
- iPad Pro (10.5 inch)
- iPad Pro (9.7 inch)
- iPhone 7 Plus
- iPhone 7
- iPhone SE
- iPhone 4s

[image: Xcode Available Devices Subset]

I hope the question is not off topic, because it isn't really about programming but program usage. What have I done, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluntly put: "view as" ≠ simulator.

Those "view as" options are to preview different viewport resolutions with storyboards and are independent from simulator selection. As the resolutions are common with multiple devices (ie. iPhone 6 = 6s = 7) it is unnecessary to list them all. You could think of it as a visual preview.

The device list next to Play/Stop is the actual simulator selector list and choosing one will fire up an actual simulator when running.

Comment: Sorry, that was a Red Herring statement from me. (I was trying to quell any answers suggesting that I should choose a simulator in the scheme editor.) All of the devices listed were available to me yesterday as a "View as" option.

Comment: It was a combination of automatic updates and undocumented changes in Xcode 8.3.3.